# jQuery late binding of Ajax elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm really stuck with a jQuery issue and I hope someone can help me out...

So I have a list of options on the left, and when you click on one, a form is generated via Ajax on the right. There's this element in the form:

```
<input type="text" class="value" value="something">
```

And what I want to do is to call

```
$(".value").tagsInput();
```

which is a jQuery plugin that works pretty much like Stack Overflow's 'Tags' input field when you ask a question.

So I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".value").on("load", function () {
    console.log("Tags Input");
    $(".value").tagsInput();
  });
});
```

and nothing is printed out. I've also tried this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".value", function () {
  console.log("Tags Input");
  $(".value").tagsInput();
});
```

and it doesn't work either. I'm wondering where I did wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Link to your plugin? They most likely have their own events

Comment: @OptimusCrime link is http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/. But I think it should at least print `Tags Input` in the console?

Comment: can't you bind $(".value").tagsInput(); in your success function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Shabnam, the "change" event is *not* what you want, as it is fired only once the field is blurred.

Anyways, from the plugin documentation, it looks like you don't have to call that function every time a key is pressed, but it attaches its own event handlers autonomously.

So, probably you should be fine with just:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".value").tagsInput();
});
```

Your `.on` handler will never work, as the `load` event is fired only by `document` when the page is ready.

If you want to debug things a bit, have a look at the supported callbacks, such as `onChange`.

**SIDE NOTE**

I don't like how that plugin is written, as it clogs the "global" `jQuery.fn` namespace with lots of functions, while jQuery documentation recommends not doing so (see: [Namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing)).

**UPDATE**

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aFPHL/ an example of this working (the `.load()` was monkeypatched to avoid having to call an actual URL, but its behavior is pretty much the same as the real one).

Comment: But when the page is first loaded there's no `".value"` yet. I only add the form later, via Ajax. So I don't think simply `$(".value").tagsInput();` will bind it... @.@

Comment: if you're loading that form via ajax, you will have to manually call ``.tagsInput()`` in the ``load()`` callback.. if you don't want to do so, I suspect you'd have to patch the plugin in order to make it use ``.on`` instead of ``.bind`` to attach event handlers

Comment: sorry I don't quite get it. Where should I call `.tagsInput()`? Which `load()` callback are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle example :)

Answer (score 0):

"change" event gets fired when the input element loses focus. If you want ajax call at the end of each key input, try using keyboard events